# how to create a generic class structure

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a requirement where user selects a ReportType from a dropdown and hits download button.Based on his type chosen, the system should generate a report. Right now i have only report type that is QuoteReport. In future i will have other report types like PolicyReport,ClaimReport. Right now i have no idea what will be data-fields in these reports too.

```
public class QuoteReport
{
  public String DeviceType { get; set; }
  public String ProductName { get; set; }
  public String Description { get; set; }
  public String ID { get; set; }
  public String Address { get; set; }     
}
```

Now What I am doing is I send reporttype and paramters to fill the report and i have created a switch case to catch type of report being selected.

```
public string PrepareReport(string selectedReport, List<int> Ids)
{
    string response = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        ReportTypeEnum reportTypeEnum;
        if (Enum.TryParse(selectedReport, out reportTypeEnum))
        {
            switch (reportTypeEnum)
            {
                case ReportTypeEnum.QuoteReport:
                    response = CreateReportData(Ids,response);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        handleException(DOWNLOAD_REPORT, exc);
    }
    return response;
}
```

My method CreateReportData fills the fields of QuoteReport class from wcf.

```
 public string CreateReportData(List<int> Ids, string response)
 {
    List<QuoteReport> quoteReportList = new List<QuoteReport>();            
    foreach (var Id in Ids)
    {
        dynamic dynamicEntity;
        List<string> devices = proxy.GetData(Id);
        for (int i = 0; i < devices.Count; i++)
        {
            QuoteReport quoteReport = new QuoteReport();
            dynamicEntity = JObject.Parse(devices[i]);
            quoteReport.Type = dynamicEntity.DeviceTypeString;
            quoteReport.ProductName = dynamicEntity.ProductName;
            quoteReport.Description = dynamicEntity.Desc;
            quoteReport.ID = dynamicEntity.ID;
            assetReport.Address = dynamicEntity.Address;
             quoteReportList.Add(quoteReport );

        }
    }
    response = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(quoteReportList );
    return response;
}
```

Now I am perplexed how can i make my code more generic. Or Shall i use some design patterns like Factory to make code adaptable for future needs. How Can I make CreateReportData  method generic so that it accepts any class type and fills up its properties from service.

Comment: Question is too undefined/broad for SO in current state. It may be good idea to wait with refactoring till you actually know your use case. Writing generic code for single case is hard and likely not be useful when you introduce other cases.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Should i be using any design pattern to create a structure

Comment: Don't use a switch - use a `Dictionary<Type, Func<string>>` (or something similar) to enable dynamically creating different types. Also, please never ever code `catch (Exception exc)` - you should **only** ever catch errors that you can specifically recover from.

Answer (score 2):

Im not going to rewrite all (you have som naming issues and separation of conserns issues) but in general terms, you can have an interface `IReport` that has a signature `Generate(List<int> Ids)` and then every type of report implements this (and the class/report itself decides what to do with the data)

```
public class QuoteReport: IReport
{
  public String DeviceType { get; set; }
  public String ProductName { get; set; }
  public String Description { get; set; }
  public String ID { get; set; }
  public String Address { get; set; }  

  public void Generate(List<int> ids)
  {
        // create "itself"
  }   
}
```

Depending on your generic cases, you decide where to draw the separation, and whats get passed to the Generate(). It could be a list of devices, or your proxy+ids